# Basis Functions with Learnable Parameters

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

When we use least squares to fit a linear basis function model:

$y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1b_1(x_i) +\beta_2b_2(x_i)+\beta_3b_3(x_i)+...+\beta_kb_k(x_i)+\epsilon_i$

Is it possible to fit a model where the $b_i$ have parameters that we fit?

So for example if my original basis function is $b(x)=ln(x)$, is there any way to instead fit a model where I use a basis function $b(x)=ln(x+c)$ where c is a learnable parameter? Then the model would be:

$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1ln(x_i+c)+\epsilon_i$.

Also is it possible to have basis functions which are compositions of some set of functions where the composition is learned. For example I could have a set $\{g_1(x),g_2(x),g_3(x),...\}$. Then my basis functions could be arbitrary compositions of the functions in this set.

EDIT: I came up with the following neural network:

[image]

I computed the gradients for the computational graph above and I got the following:

$\partial L/\partial c = 2(\hat{y}-y)\beta_1/f$

$\partial L/\partial \beta_0=2(\hat{y}-y)$

$\partial L/\partial \beta_1 = 2(\hat{y}-y)ln(f)$

Then I wrote a short Python program to use the gradients to perform gradient descent. It seems to work quite well.

With 50 data points generated from y=ln(x-1) I get the model:

$-0.124+1.092*ln(x-0.939)$

which lies almost exactly over the graph of y=ln(x-1).

````py
def step(x, c, beta_1, beta_0, y, step_size=0.001):
    f=x+c
    import math
    g=beta_1*math.log(f)
    y_hat = beta_0 + g
    dLdc = 2*(y_hat-y)*beta_1/f
    dLdB0 = 2*(y_hat-y)
    dLdB1 = 2*(y_hat-y)*math.log(f)
    return (c-step_size*dLdc, beta_0-dLdB0*step_size, beta_1-step_size*dLdB1)

def gradient_descent(xs, ys):
    c = 1
    beta_0 = 1
    beta_1 = 1
    
    NUM_EPOCHS=1000
    
    for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        for i in range(len(xs)):
            c, beta_0, beta_1 = step(xs[i], c, beta_1, beta_0, ys[i])
    
    return (c, beta_0, beta_1)

# Generate 100 data points from y = ln(x-1)
import math
xs = []
ys = []
for i in range(100):
    x = 1.1+0.1*i
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(math.log(x-1))
    
# Compute the parameters to use in our model of y=ln(x-1)
# Should return c=-0.9999666014854611, B0=-8.636312629709472e-05 B1=1.0000446912552832
# Therefore our model of y=ln(x-1) generated from the 100 data points is:
# y = -8.636312629709472e-05+1.0000446912552832*ln(x-0.9999666014854611)
# which lies almost exactly over the graph of y=ln(x-1)
gradient_descent(xs, ys)
```
````

Comment: What you propose certainly is possible and has considerable similarities to how a neural network works. A particular software implementation is off-topic here, but there’s nothing wrong with having additional parameters in the basis functions and then estimating them from the loss function $argmin$ like we normally do. (The regression will be nonlinear, which could pose challenges, depending on your goals.)

Comment: @Dave what kind of optimisation algorithm could you use to find the minimum of such a loss function? I'm guessing there is no 'silver bullet' and you might need to use a different algorithm depending on the particular basis function/loss function. Is the problem generally solvable if the loss function is concave/convex?

Comment: @Dave Could I simply use a neural network where I have: $x->(x+c)->\beta_1ln(x+c)->(\beta_0+\beta_1ln(x+c))->y$ and then train it using backpropagation? Where $\beta_0, \beta_1, c$ are learnable parameters.

Comment: I think you might find projection pursuit regression algorithms interesting https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_pursuit_regression